# Google Data Studio Gives Error When a 3rd Schema Attribute is Added

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I have created a Custom Community Connector that currently has a schema with two attributes. A Metric: Budget Amount, and a Dimension: Budget Name. These are pulled from an API from another site. When linking this connector to a Data Studio project I am able to create a Pie Chart that displays all Budget names and amounts.

However, once I add a third attribute of any kind (ex. Metric: Budget Spent or Dimension: Company Name) the pie chart no longer shows and displays an error :
Script error message: 
 Script error cause: UNKNOWN
 Script error stacktrace:

I have confirmed that data is flowing correctly by using logs within Apps Scripts and with the Table chart in Data Studio. The Table Chart is the only table that will show up but only when all possible Metrics and Dimensions are apart of it.

I am currently looking for anyway to debug this, solutions, or advice on where to go from here. I would like to expand the Schema, however I cannot continue if charts stop working when I add more attributes.

If more information or code is needed let me know and I will provide whatever is needed. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

The [Debugging Guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/debug) should get you started with the debug. I recommend you use [Stackdriver logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) to log the request and response for each function. You can see an example of logging [here](https://github.com/google/datastudio/tree/master/community-connectors/stackoverflow-questions).